# Weird behavior of MySQL PDO querys

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a really weird problem, and I can't figure out a solution to it. ($DB id PDO object)

```
$type = 'some_type';      
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `last_save` WHERE `type` = :type;";
$st = $DB->prepare($sql);      
$st->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
$rows = $st->fetchAll();
var_dump($rows);
```

$rows is empty array

```
array(0) { }
```

although there are rows in the database that query should fetch.

My table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `last_save` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` text,
  `parameter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm really running out of ideas here, and any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty crazy to be doing a `WHERE` on a `TEXT` column, especially one that's not indexed. Shouldn't that be something simple like `VARCHAR`?

Comment: note: you don't need to terminate your lines with `;` in a pdo query

Comment: delete the very last semicolon!

Comment: Also you should check the return value of `$st->execute()`, it will return false if the query fails.

Comment: did you try running that query manually? `SHOULD` is not the same as `WILL`.

Comment: Are you SURE you have rows for that  particular type?  `An empty array is returned if there are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure`

Comment: @boulder_02: that does nothing.

Comment: OK, @tadman, you are right, it is crazy to be doing a WHERE on a TEXT column. I converted it to INT added a row with 0 in it and then did the same query with PDO::PARAM_INT and it didn't work.

Comment: I also removed a semicolon and it did nothing. $st->execute() returns false which is also strange.

Comment: Even more weird is that "SELECT * FROM `last_save`" is also returning false and 0 rows
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(25) "SELECT * FROM `last_save`" } 
bool(false) 
array(0) { }

Comment: did you select the right database>?

Comment: you should catch the last pdo error...

Comment: @Sebas this is what I'm getting in the $st->errorInfo();
`Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.`

Comment: So, I guess that some of the previous queries is causing an error?

Comment: Do you have any other code running before the code you presented?

Comment: Yes! That is it! So, I had to use $st->closeCursor() on one of the previous queries to make this one work. OMG, would have never thought of it.  
Thank you all on your amazing help, it is very appreciated!

Comment: You know, this problem would have been solved in 10 seconds if you had not obfuscated essential information to us.

Comment: @Sebas yes, you are right. The thing is that I didn't know that these information mean anything. This is first time I'm using PDO, and before results of one query didn't influence the other ones. :)
Also, I never checked if $st->execute returns false.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears clean, check your pdo connection params. And if your storing special characters in your table, add the "SET NAMES utf8" to your config, like:

```
$DB =  new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', 'user', 'pass', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Without further testing I think you don't have to put the quotes and the semicolon in your select statement.
Try it like so:

```
SELECT * FROM last_save WHERE type = :type
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. Tried it tens of times in different variations.

Comment: did you remove the quotes from table name, too?

Comment: I tested it out but the quotes and semicolon doesn't matter. When I use your code in my own environment I can't seem to find any problems. Make sure your database connection is working otherwise check if the record with "some_type" exists in you table